Barrier Puts Pricing (down-and-in put)
I am trying to price the down-and-in put option with European Style (when barrier level < strike price) by using Black Scholes Option Pricing model.
but after checking the formula several times, I am still struggling with the negative put price (Pdi).
Can someone tell me where my formula / input is wrong?
Thank you

